# Convert existing mobile app on store to a PWA

Tags: app-store, progressive-web-apps, mobile-application, pwabuilder

We currently have two native mobile applications (Android and iOS).
These applications are on the stores (Playstore / Appstore), and have passed all the checks. They've been there for a while, and we've got lots of data, and lots of users using them.
We've created a PWA using the PWAbuilder site, which offers us 2 packages, which we can also publish on the stores.
My question is, in order to migrate mobile users to the PWa as easily as possible, and avoid having 2 points on the stores. Would it be possible to replace the mobile app with the PWA on the stores? So that it's completely transparent for users and they don't have to install anything new?

Thanks a lot!